# I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate 3 variables into my tail recursion code for racket

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Write a tail recursive function called popadd that models a population with P people at time t = 0 and adds d people per year.

```
(define (popadd t  P)
  (if (= t 0)
      P
  (+(popadd( - t 1) P)d)) 
)
```

but, of course, I get the error that d hasn't been defined yet, which is true. I tried adding it as an input, but as a return I get the number inserted for D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pass along another parameter to the recursion:

```
(define (popadd t P d)
  (if (= t 0)
      P
      (+ d (popadd (- t 1) P d))))
```

Or you can define the value, to avoid passing it around - assuming it doesn't need to change:

```
(define d 100)

(define (popadd t P)
  (if (= t 0)
      P
      (+ d (popadd (- t 1) P))))
```

Notice that you could do the same with `P`, if it's ok. It really depends on what's the expected contract for the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Note that neither your code nor the code in the other answer is tail-recursive: in a recursive call like `(+ (f ...))`, `f` is not in tail position.  To make the code tail-recursive you need the result of the recursive call be the result of the overall call (so in the above example, `+` *is* in tail position).  To do this you need an auxiliary function.  Here is a way of doing it which relies only on local `define`:

```
(define (popadd t P d)
  (define (popadd-loop tau pop)
    (if (zero? tau)
        pop
        (popadd-loop (- tau 1) (+ pop d))))
  (popadd-loop t P))
```

Here is essentially the same thing using named-`let`, which is nicer:

```
(define (popadd t P d)
  (let popadd-loop ([tau t] [pop P])
    (if (zero? tau)
        pop
        (popadd-loop (- tau 1) (+ pop d)))))
```

Finally note that this problem has a closed-form solution:

```
(define (popadd t P d)
  (+ P (* t d)))
```

I *really wish* that people trying to teach programming knew enough maths to *not* set problems which have trivial closed-form answers, as doing so encourages people to write inefficient (in the complexity-class sense) code.  Obviously this is not your fault: it's your teacher's.